# Exported file download using ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm adding CSV export to a service implemented with ASP.NET Web API.

Currently I have a view model (containing details of results filtering), which is sent to a Web API controller via a ajax POST request. The JSON response is then rendered on UI. This works just fine.

Now I want to post the same view model to another controller, let us name it `ExportController`. Then I need to download the file to the user.

My idea:

1. Post the view model to the service, store it somewhere in persistent storage (DB or in-memory cache, does not matter) and return an export token to a user. (By export token I mean a piece of information used to identify this particular export)
2. Then execute a `GET` request from an `iframe` with that token in URL
   and get the file as the response to this request.

What I have by now, on UI:

```
var exportUrl = "URL to ExportController"
$.ajax(exportUrl, {
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: postData
})
.success(function(data) {
    // this should download the file
    $('#export').attr('src', exportUrl + '&exportToken=' + data);
});
```

Here '#export' is the `iframe` element used to download the file.

And here is a raw sketch of export backend:

```
public class ExportController : ApiController
{
    ...

    // GET /api/Export
    public string Get(string exportToken)
    {
        // get filters from DB
        var filters = ExportArgumentProvider.GetFilters(exportToken);

        // get data
        var result = DataSource.GetData(filters);

        return result;
    }

    // POST /api/Export
    public string Post(FilterInput filters)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        // save filters to DB
        ExportArgumentProvider.AddFilter(guid, filters);

        return guid.ToString();
    }
}
```

*This pseudo-code obviously does not work, please ignore the return type of Get method.*

**So, questions:**

1. Is there easier way to make this export (without storing filter state in DB).
2. Is this approach sane (state stored in DB etc.), or such tasks should be done in another way?
3. Is ASP.NET Web API a good fit for such tasks or I should resort to usual ASP.NET controllers for export?

**UPDATE**: data posted to the server may exceed URL lenght limits, so passing it via a GET request is not really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this project I gave up creating clean and RESTful backend and converted `ExportController` into a usual MVC controller. Then I was able to change this line in `Post` method

```
ExportArgumentProvider.AddFilter(guid, filters);
```

into

```
Session[exportId] = filters;
```

and do the same thing with the `Get` method.

I still think that approach with storing filters in DB is much better, but

1. I don't really need REST API here.
2. It introduces too much overhead into the code, much more than I would like to add 'just for the sake of purity of the API'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just combining the two requests into one: make the "export" URL take all of the parameters are do the export "on the fly". There is a slight limitation that you can only stuff so much data into the querystring, so this may not work for you, but I would suggest going for it (as it will simplify the problem quite a bit).

Assuming the "postData" (in the first part of the component) is "small enough" then you simply need to serialize it into the querystring of your "export" URL and then combine the endpoints together (such that the export URL handles the filtering of data/etc).

Comment: The fact that `postData` is not small enough is the key to all the problems :(

Comment: You could have your iframe do the post for you and still have the "combined" endpoint deal with everything.

Comment: How exactly is it implemented?